# How to append variable in an URL of Liferay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, liferay

I am trying to append some variable in my Liferay URL from which i am calling a serveResorce now the problem is that i want to append some value with it ,the value should be $('#id).val() with that URL ,how to do that because when i am hardcoding the value t the url then it is working but i want that a value which can be dynamic will be there,How to do that ,like i am posting my code

```
<a href='#' onClick="location.href = '<portlet:resourceURL></portlet:resourceURL>&<portlet:namespace/>consultantID='+document.getElementById('LULU').value'&<portlet:namespace/>companyName='+document.getElementById('LULUComp').value+&<portlet:namespace/>type=createExcelForConsultant'">LULU</a>
```

This is the URL which is working fine and the 7 is going to the server but i want to place a $('#id).val() in the place of the 7 ,how to do that somebody please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You replace `+7+` with this:

```
+ document.getElementById('id').value +
```

Comment: thanks for your help man it worked for can you do a little more ??can you inspect the edited post  that when i am trying to add two more fields with your code where i am getting wrong??

Answer (score 1):

A good practice in this scenario would be creating URL through Liferay's javascript API as following:

**On click event call to javascript method:**

```
<a href='#' onClick="onClickLULU();">LULU</a>
```

**Javascript method:**

```
function onClickLULU(){
    var consultantID = document.getElementById('LULU').value;
    var companyName = document.getElementById('LULUComp').value;

    var resourceURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createResourceURL();
        resourceURL.setParameter("consultantID", consultantID);
        resourceURL.setParameter("companyName", companyName);
        resourceURL.setParameter("type", "createExcelForConsultant");

    location.href = resourceURL;
}
```

Reference: [Working with Liferay URLs](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/11/working-with-liferay-urls.html)